# How can I utilize an index with a different type or collation in a LEFT JOIN in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.7, cast

I am trying to debug a slow query, and when I `EXPLAIN` the SQL, I get a warning:

```
Warning: #1739 Cannot use ref access on index '[index name]' due to type or collation conversion on field '[field name]'
```

The query is quite complex, so I have made an example setup that gets the same warning, the SQL is below, as well as a db fiddle (although the db fiddle doesn't show the warning, so I don't know much help that is!).

The original query is

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `t1` LEFT JOIN `t2` ON `t2`.`ext_id`=`t1`.`id` WHERE 1;
```

I also tried

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `t1` LEFT JOIN `t2` ON `t2`.`ext_id`=CAST(`t1`.`id` AS CHAR) WHERE 1;
```

but that doesn't allow the index to be utilized, and still has the same warning.

Is there any way I can utilize the index in this `LEFT JOIN`?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s89hwBtMSvcUnipKfadsuM/1

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;



INSERT INTO `t1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'n1'),
(2, 'n2');


CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `ext_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `position` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


INSERT INTO `t2` (`id`, `ext_id`, `position`) VALUES
(1, '1', 'p1'),
(2, '2', 'p2');

ALTER TABLE `t1`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `t2`
  ADD KEY `ext_id` (`ext_id`) USING BTREE;
```

Edit: Using MySQL 5.7

Comment: What version of MySQL is being used? If recent enough, you could use a functional index / virtual column: [MySQL 8.0 Functional Indexes](https://www.percona.com/blog/mysql-8-0-functional-indexes/)

Comment: It's on 5.7 unfortunately

Comment: Honestly with 5.7, your best bet probably is to convert the table to proper data types and have a convert as the data hits it. Or you can use something like synonyms and triggers to then populate another table and that table has the new data types / joins and indexes.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't convert the table to "proper" data types, as the table with the `varchar` could contain non-integers for entries unrelated to this query. My best bet, if it's not possible to join as per my example, is probably to create and populate a temporary table, `ALTER`ing the type of that field after creation/population, for when I need to run this query

Comment: Why does `ext_id` need to be `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Because it stores external ids from various other sources, some of which are strings, some are ints.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 5.7, you can create a generated column and add an index to it. The only difference between this an MySQL 8.0 is that 8.0 allows you to create an index on an expression without adding the generated column.

```
ALTER TABLE `t2`
  ADD COLUMN ext_id_int INT AS (CAST(ext_id AS SIGNED)),
  ADD KEY `ext_id` (`ext_id_int`);
```

(It's not necessary to specify USING BTREE because that's the only type of index InnoDB supports on an INT column.)

Then you join on that generated column, and it will use the index:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `t1` LEFT JOIN `t2` 
  ON `t2`.`ext_id_int`=`t1`.`id` 
WHERE 1;
```

Given the very small example data you show, EXPLAIN will still show it doing a table-scan, but it will use the index if you have a more substantial dataset, or if you use an index hint to tell it a table-scan is to be avoided if possible:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `t1` LEFT JOIN `t2` FORCE INDEX (ext_id) 
  ON `t2`.`ext_id_int`=`t1`.`id` 
WHERE 1;
```

Comment: Ideally I would avoid altering the table as it has millions of rows, so adding another index and column isn't a great option. Creating a temporary table with just the relevant rows and altering the temporary table so the `ext_id` column is an `INT`, then LEFT JOINing on the temporary table seems to be the best way forward.

Comment: As you wish. I'll leave my answer here for other readers who may have a similar query, and want to optimize it properly. :-)